# Unable to use readxl::read_excel and xlsx::write.xlsx at the same time

Tags: r, excel, import, export, xlsx

I used 2 approaches.

1. When I tried to use `readxl::read_excel`to read my files into R, I couldn't use `xlsx::write.xlsx` to export it to excel after all the computations.

Upon loading the package, it showed:

```
library(xlsx)
# Loading required package: rJava
# Loading required package: xlsxjars
# Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
#   call: .jinit()
#   error: Cannot create Java virtual machine (-4)
# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’
```

When I tried `XLConnect`, it showed something similar:

```
# library(XLConnect)
# Loading required package: XLConnectJars
# Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'XLConnectJars', details:
#   call: .jinit()
#   error: Cannot create Java virtual machine (-1)
# Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded
```

2. When I loaded both libraries before importing any data, they could be loaded with ease. But when I tried to import the data, one of them gave:

`Error: std::bad_alloc`

How can I rectify this?

Comment: We unfortunately need `sessionInfo()` output to even begin diagnosing. Java version info would also be helpful. I guess I'd ask why you're mixing pkgs, tho. I grok that `readxl` is 'nicer' but `xlsx` can read excel data just fine, too. Introducing the extra dependency is (IMO) not worth it.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I think the issue is that `readxl` can't write to .xls/.xlsx. I'd just write a .csv and import that into Excel if necessary. I suspect it's a Java issue; I seem to be having it too (unrelated to `readxl`) now that I've updated to macOS Sierra. Sierra did drop support for Java 6, which may be the issue.

Comment: Aye, hence why I suggested just using `xlsx` for the OP. I've tried to stay away from pkgs that require/depend on Java 6 on macOS for a while, now, tho. Keeping those binaries on one's system—esp in std locations—is (even without browser applets) still a fairly important security issue.

Comment: @hrbrmstr xlsx is taking way too long to read my excel files, hence I decided on readxl. Plus, I have 72 files to read. I can't convert them to csv too because converting to csv will correct cells with error, which I don't want it to happen. I have cells like "6810109023E000101" that becomes "6.81E+110" upon conversion to csv. I guess I just have to fall on xlsx back.

Comment: [`openxlsx`](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx) does the job without Java and can still write to Excel, so for now I'm ditching `XLConnect` and `xlsx`. `readxl` in, .csv out is still my first choice, though.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for the suggestion! But I don't think `openxlsx` supports large data. I tried to write the R data into excel, it returned `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 28.4 Mb`.

Comment: Oof, I'm not sure I'd want to stick something that big in an Excel file anyway. If I can't visually inspect all the data, it needs to be under glass so bugs don't inadvertently get introduced without a reproducible trail.

Comment: I thought `detach()`-ing the first package before loading the second package would work, but it still gives me `Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: Cannot create Java virtual machine (-1)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’`